# Select two columns just side by side as join is resulting in multiple entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Two Tables]

The output should be just the two columns along side. In case one column has more values, output should just show null in the other column.
Facing this difficulty as this somehow is on the fringe of SQL table definition itself.

Comment: and for this data what output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and `full join`:

```
select me.me, pn.pnname
from (select me.*,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from me
     ) me full join
     (select pn.*,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      frompn
     ) pn
     on me.seqnum = pn.seqnum;
```

Note that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so the results are in an arbitrary order.  If you want a particular order in each column, then put that information in the `order by`.

Comment: And you add more arbitrariness by not including an order by column. Which is a bit of an oxymoron since the tables and the desired goal have no particular ordering as far as we know

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.